# hashicorp Vault : " Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert " Where is my mistake?

Tags: https, docker-compose, openssl, hashicorp-vault, vault

I try to run Vault with docker-compose on Virtual machine ubuntu 20.04 ( ip : 192.168.56.9 ). Without the https, already works fine, but when I try to put vault in https with self-signed certificat from openssl, it doesn't works.

Here my configurations :

**docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  vault:
    build:
      context: ./vault
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    volumes:
      - ./vault/config:/vault/config
      - ./vault/policies:/vault/policies
      - ./vault/data:/vault/data
      - ./vault/logs:/vault/logs
      - ./vault/volume_test/:/vault/volume_test
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://192.168.56.9:8200
    command: server -config=/vault/config/vault-config.conf
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
```

**Dockerfile** :

```
# base image
FROM alpine:3.7

# set vault version
ENV VAULT_VERSION 0.10.3

# create a new directory
RUN mkdir /vault

# download dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add \
      bash \
      ca-certificates \
      wget

# download and set up vault
RUN wget --quiet --output-document=/tmp/vault.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/${VAULT_VERSION}/vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/vault.zip -d /vault && \
    rm -f /tmp/vault.zip && \
    chmod +x /vault

# update PATH
ENV PATH="PATH=$PATH:$PWD/vault"

# add the config file
COPY ./config/vault-config.conf /vault/config/vault-config.conf

# expose port 8200
EXPOSE 8200

# run vault
ENTRYPOINT ["vault"]
```

My **vault-config.conf** :

```
backend "file" {
  path = "vault/data"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = false
  tls_cert_file = "/home/xxx/Vault-Docker/domain.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/home/xxx/Vault-Docker/domain.key"
}

#api_addr = "http://192.168.56.9:8200"

disable_mlock = true

ui = true
```

How I create my **.crt** and my **.key** :

Create a cert.conf file in **/home/xxx/Vault-Docker/** :

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
C = FR
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = 192.168.56.9

[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 192.168.56.9
```

And excute in /home/xxx/Vault-Docker/ :

```
openssl req -nodes -x509 -days 365 -keyout domain.key -out domain.crt -config cert.conf
```

But when I run :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Then :

```
docker logs vault-docker_vault_1
```

The output is :

```
Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: open /home/xxx/Vault-Docker/domain.crt: no such file or directory
```

Someone to tell me where is my error ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: why didn't you specify the CA file generate by the self-signed openssl too?
and you should mount the cert to the container too from you host

Answer (score 0):

That's because your cert configuration is not mounted inside the container. In order to fix it, you need to:

1. create a new directory `./vault/cert`
2. move both `domain.crt` and `domain.key` to `./vault/cert`
3. add to `docker-compose-yml` a new volume:

```
   volumes:
...
     - ./vault/cert/:/vault/cert
...
```

4. Change on `vault-config.conf` from `/home/.../domain*` to `/vault/cert/domain*` on both `tls_cert_*` directives

Then Vault will be able to find the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the certificate path which will be the container path and you have kept the certificate in the host machine.